# WPF databound Combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, filter, combobox

I need to create a usercontrol that behaves like a combobox. 
Instances of this combobox will be databound to a certain collection at runtime. (i.e a collection of strings, to keep this question as minimal as possible).

However, this combobox needs to have an "exclusion list", which holds entries that are not shown in the dropdown list of the combobox, in the case they do appear in the databound collection. They are filtered out.

Up till this point I have managed to create a control that fullfills the requirements.

1. However, the screens that use these comboboxes are used to display objects that might have been created before certain entries were manually added to the "exclusion list" I described above. In these cases I still need to have the comboboxes show the value, even though it is in the exception list. However, in case the user tries to change the value, it should not appear in the dropdown.
2. Apart from the exclusion list, I also need to filter the remaining elements based on a simple rule. For simplicity, let's assume I don't want entries with a string length of exactly 7.

I'm very new to WPF. I have tried over and over, and I see no starting point to implement these last two requirements. I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction for a way to implement (1) and (2). I have access to infragistics 2013 in case those controls are closer to the solution.

Comment: Filtering data is not a responsibility of the View. Whay you need is a proper ViewModel, not a custom control to do this.